# Authentication issue in Docker-MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have installed MongoDB in Linux Ubuntu through the docker image. 
I have set the parameters in the YAML file like below to implement the authentication for mongodb. But when I up the server using the command `docker-compose up -d`, I'm getting error like

> "Unsupported config option for 'db' service: 'security'".

How can I resolve the issue?

`docker-compose.yaml`:

---

```
db:
   image: mongo:2.6.4
   command: ["mongod", "--smallfiles"]
   expose: "27017"
   ports: "27017:27017"
   security: keyFile: "/home/ubuntu/dockerlab/keyfile.key"
   authorization: "enabled"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`security` and `authorization` are [not a keyword](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for the `docker-compose` YAML file, so take them out of there.

If that file key file needs copying into the container, you should put something like:

```
FROM: mongo:2.6.4

ADD /home/ubuntu/dockerlab/keyfile.key /tmp
ENV AUTH yes
```

in a Dockerfile.

And change in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
image: mongo:2.6.4
```

into

```
build: .
```

and the `command` value into

```
 command: ["mongod", "--smallfiles", "--keyFile /tmp/keyfile.key" ]
```

Alternatively you can use a `volume` entry in your `docker-compose.yml` to map the `keyfile.key` into your container, and instead of the  `ENV` in the `Dockerfile` you add `, "--auth"` to sequence that is the value for `command`. Then you can continue to use the `image` stanza and leave out the `Dockerfile` altogether:

```
db:
   image: mongo:2.6.4
   command: ["mongod", "--smallfiles", "--auth", "--keyFile /tmp/keyfile.key" ]
   expose: "27017"
   ports: "27017:27017"
   volumes: 
   - /home/ubuntu/dockerlab/keyfile.key: /tmp
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now, the mongo asking user credentials to see the databases. But I'm not able to login the mongo even if i have mentioned user name and password like -- mongo --port 27017 -u admuser -p password-123 --authenticationDatabase "admin"

Comment: Then, i have tried with another syntax like mongo admin -u admuser -p password-123...but its not login into..How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: @JKG I have no idea where mongo expects a keyfile (or if it does so in the first place). Have you tried starting without `--auth` and then connecting? BTW where did you get the information from that made you construct the faulty docker-compose.yml file in the first place?

Comment: I updated the answer, but there is no way I can test this. You have to generate the correct keyfile of course, and then tell mongo where it is. As this is essentially a new question, you should pose it as a new one as your `docker-compose.yml` file issues have been solved now.

Comment: I hope --auth option itself asking for credentials (i guess authentication will work either --auth option or key file generation). So i have proceeded with that one. In another servers (Not docker images), i have used to login using this command only "mongo admin -u admuser -p password-123". But here i am not able to login

Comment: I am completely new to YAML file options, i google and got those options from this URL "https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-internal-authentication/" where it has mention as "security:  keyFile: /srv/mongodb/keyfile". so i have tried and didn't help me

Comment: yes YAML file issue resolved successfully. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Those mongo docks point to a mongo configuration file, that has nothing to do with the docker-compose YAML file.  Make sure you describe how you made your first user and how you generated your keyfile.

Comment: yes, I completely understood about the YAML file settings and now i can able to login into the mongoDB successfully with the credentials and implemented restrictions in the docker image with your help. Thanks a Lot.

Comment: @JKG If my answer solved (or significantly helped solve) the issue, please consider marking it as the accepted answer ( V to the left of the top of answer) that is the way others visiting this site know that your question has been resolved. They might not read all the way down to the comments.

Comment: The second alternative does not work anymore? I get error that `volume` is not recognized. Suggests to use `volumes`

Comment: @Dmitry That might have been a typo. The docs (now) say `volumes`, so I updated the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: But then it complains about the value for the `volumes`. I'm sorry I'm a newb in docker world, thus the low quality comment without proposing the solution

Comment: @Dmitry The value for `volumes` has to be a [sequence](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#volumes). I once more updated the answer